# Windows Built In FS Conversion tool?

Tags: windows-8, filesystems, ntfs, exfat

Can I use convert.exe to convert my ExFat drive (Which is 3TB and not the boot drive, if that matters) to NTFS?

I'm in Windows 8, and I SERIOUSLY need to convert my drive, preferably without data loss.

Comment: Not that it helps, but why did you even decide to format a 3TB drive as exFAT and not NTFS?

Comment: I don't know honestly, I was thinking that NTFS may somehow mess something up or would be slower than exfat, there's no reasoning to it tbh.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I have [found online](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-hardware/how-can-i-convert-my-usb-memory-stick-from-exfat/31b9611e-d06f-442a-8166-615368a91202) running convert.exe on a exFAT drive will give you the error "CONVERT is not available for EXFAT drives."

It appears you will need to copy the data off, format the drive, then copy it back on. There is no in-place way to change the filesystem inplace.

(If you don't have a spare drive to copy to, you can play "leapfrog" and use a [partition re-sizing program](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/) and make a new NTFS partion out of the free space. Once you have done that go back in to windows and copy all you can. After that go back in to the partition program and shrink the exFAT partition and grow the NTFS one. Keep repeating till you have copied all of your files.)

Comment: If you are getting errors I would recommend AGAINST doing the "leapfrog technique"

Comment: I hope I don't sound like too much of a newb, but what's the leapfrog technique?

Comment: The thing I put in the last paragraph of my answer, you may need to refresh the page.

Comment: Idk why I didn't think of that, I'll try it thanks man.

Comment: NO!!!!! If you are getting filesystem errors DO NOT TRY IT!

Comment: Why not though? and I've found a spare 1TB drive, that I can atleast copy off some of my stuff with...

Comment: The thing that is causing your errors now, will make the drive unreadable when it tries to do the resize. YOU WILL LIKELY LOOSE ALL OF YOUR FILES IF YOU TRY IT!

Comment: Okay, thanks man. Ill just have to copy off a TB's worth and try to cram it onto other computer's I've got lying around here, they should collectively hold all my stuff. thanks for the advice.